# set nobomb not removing byte order mark in vim

Tags: python, vim, byte-order-mark

I want to remove `\xef\xbb\xbf` marks (BOM) from my file. It's a text file to be fed to python, and the BOM marks are causing problems there. I tried `:set nobomb` but those are still there. How can I solve this problem and what might have caused this problem?

**UPDATE:**
My file is obtained by combining (concatenating) many other files (using obabel software) each of which has BOM. So, probably *set nobomb* removes BOM mark only at the beginning of the new file. In such cases, how can I remove all BOMs?

Comment: Checking the obvious first, did you save in the same session that you did the `:set nobomb`? From the Vim help: `When you don't change the options, the BOM will be restored when writing the file.` Or another possibility: was your vim config already set to `nobomb` by default? If so, then `:set nobomb` wouldn't delete the BOM character because the options wouldn't have changed.

Comment: I saved in the same session. I looked into my vimrc file but did not find anything related to BOM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the byte sequences are embedded in your buffer, a

```
:%substitute/\%ufeff//g
```

might already do the trick.

Comment: This does not do, The patter I get <feff> is not matched to it and some variations I tried.

Comment: @DurgaDatta Yep, assuming the UTF-8 filetype and proper encoding, it should probably be `\%ufeff`, at least that worked for me.

Comment: It worked now, I might have made some mistake earlier. Thank you.

Comment: What does %u mean? What are other similar encoding?

Comment: Ah, great! %u is for a 4-digit Unicode value, %x for 2-digit byte. See `:help /\%u`